# Socket.io null in room

Tags: socket.io

Is it possible to have `null` in a socket.io room?

I mean when I am listing my rooms (`io.sockets.manager.rooms`) I get this:

```
 ["":[ ... ], "/dwQmEetnGTuHlLwwGe71rDG5":[null]...]
```

It seems strange to me to get `[null]` in a room, which supposed to hold the `socketID` for that room.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.
`io.sockets.manager.rooms` returns list of all the rooms which is supposed to be null if you don't have any rooms. If you want to get all clients in a room then use:

```
io.sockets.clients('room name');
```

And this returns socket instances of all clients in that specific room.